# PowerBI - Returning the current state of a single effort when there are numerous user stories pointing to the same effort

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I know this is absolutely not even close to the best practice right now, but I need to build this mockup to show how poor this current process is before I can push to implement a cleaner way of reporting...

So we are currently going through a migration effort that consists of many sites. In ADO, each site's progress is tracked by several user stories -- and no, features are not tracking sites 1:1 either. Essentially each unique site has a 1:N relationship to user stories.

Each user story is categorized by tags into 1 of 3 milestone categories. E.g. A site may have 8 user stories: 3 in milestone_1, 3 in milestone_2, 2 in milestone_3. All user stories under milestone_1 have to be completed before user stories under milestone_2 can begin, so at any given time there should only be 1 user story active for a specific site.

Now, for example, to return the current status of site_1, my thinking is I have to check all of the user stories with the tag site_1, and identify the story that has state = Active, and return the milestone tag to get its current status.

I'm not quite sure if PowerBI even has the ability to do what I stated above, so I'm at a bit of a loss here. Again, this tracking process sucks and it's been done manually since before my time. I'm here trying to automate the whole process by starting from scratch and just revamping the whole thing, but leadership is being very resistant to change, and I'm going to have to prove it to them why it's not worth it to do it this way.

I'm honestly very lost with how I can even get the logic going in PowerBI, so I haven't tried much.